# How can I check-in a single hunk inside a file using Visual Studio Team Foundation Version Control?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

My question is simple, I have a solution tracked by TF and I've made various changes to one of the files in it. In the current check-in I just want to commit one of those changes. How can I make that happen? I've done this with Git, but can't find out how to do it with VS and Team Foundation.